# Determine which variable is being accessed

Tags: ruby

For example, I have a Temperature class with both `@fahrenheit` and `@celsius` instance variables.

I also have two methods `in_fahrenheit` and `in_celsius` that converts temperatures.

The instance variables are initialized using a constructor that can take in option hashes.

Is there any possible way to implement the methods in a way so that if the rspec is

```
Temperature.new(:f => 212).in_celsius.should == 100
```

and

```
Temperature.new(:c => 50).in_celsius.should == 50
```

the method could tell what option hash is being accessed and return the right one?

One way that I know of is to just remove the `@fahrenheit` variable and just convert the `@celsius` variable automatically depending on if the option hash `include?` a `:f` or `:c`.

Comment: I would definitely go with an option you state in the last paragraph. It doesn't make sence to have both vars in the class - just a source of bugs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use classes? You could implement a factory method and return an instance of either `Fahrenheit` or `Celsius`, depending on the provided key:

```
module Temperature
  def self.parse(hash)
    if hash.has_key? :f
      Fahrenheit.new(hash[:f])
    elsif hash.has_key? :c
      Celsius.new(hash[:c])
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
Temperature.parse(f: 212)               #=> 212 °F
Temperature.parse(f: 212).in_celsius    #=> (100/1) °C
Temperature.parse(c: 50)                #=> 50 °C
Temperature.parse(c: 50).in_celsius     #=> 50 °C
Temperature.parse(c: 50).in_fahrenheit  #=> (122/1) °F

Temperature.parse(c: 100) == Temperature.parse(f: 212) #=> true
```

I'm using [rational numbers](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Rational.html) here to avoid rounding errors.

Implementations for the `Fahrenheit` and `Celsius` classes used in the above example:

```
require 'rational'

module Temperature

  class Fahrenheit
    attr_reader :value

    def initialize(value)
      @value = value
    end

    def ==(other)
      value == other.in_fahrenheit.value
    end

    def in_fahrenheit
      self
    end

    def in_celsius
      Celsius.new(Rational(5, 9) * (@value - 32))
    end

    def inspect
      "#{@value.inspect} °F"
    end
  end

  class Celsius
    attr_reader :value

    def initialize(value)
      @value = value
    end

    def ==(other)
      value == other.in_celsius.value
    end

    def in_fahrenheit
      Fahrenheit.new(Rational(9, 5) * @value + 32)
    end

    def in_celsius
      self
    end

    def inspect
      "#{@value.inspect} °C"
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have something simple as

```
def in_celsius
  result = @celsius
  result ||= (@fahrenheit - 32 ) * 5.0 / 9
  result
end
```

and the relevant method for `in_fahrenheit`

The only thing you need for this to work is to initialize the correct instance variable, `@celsius` or `@fahrenheit`

eg

```
if opts[:f] != nil
  @fahrenheit = opts[:f]
elsif opts[:c] != nil
  @celsius = opts[:c]
end
```

Comment: So this is short circuiting? This is a cool concept. Do you think you could supply me with another case example of when to use it?

Comment: you can use it for control flow (as shown above) and for memoization eg `@variable ||= a_very_expensive_operation`

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this, because I think a class should always store its data in the most simple format (in this case the SI Unit Kelvin). Furthermore I like `new` methods that work like expected (in this case take a kelvin unit and use the hash as a fallback).

```
class Temperatur
  attr_accessor :kelvin

  def initialize(degree)
    if degree.is_a?(Numeric)
      @kelvin = kelvin
    else
      @kelvin = from_celsius(args[:c]) || from_fahrenheit(args[:f])
    end
  end

  def fahrenheit
    @kelvin * 1,8 - 459,67
  end

  def celsius
    @kelvin + 273,15
  end

private

  def from_fahrenheit(fahrenheit)
    if fahrenheit
      (fahrenheit.to_f + 459,67) * 5 ⁄ 9
    end
  end

  def from_celsius(celsius)
    if celsius
      celsius.to_f - 273,15
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I like this approach, seems clean. What I don't fancy about it is the fact that you always do the convertion from Kelvin to F and C.

Comment: I think it is not worth it to optimize this with caching. This calculations are really simple and fast. Adding memoize to the method would make the class more complex especially when someone updates (changes) the temperature like this `t = Temperatur.new(10); t.celsius; t.kelvin = 20; t.celsius` and you need to invalidate the cache. As I said, not worth it.